# Showing $f(x,y)=(e^x \cos y,e^x \sin y)$ is $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$

Tags: polar-coordinates

Show $f(x,y)=(e^x \cos y,e^x \sin y)$ is $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to  \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus  (0,0)$

So I need to show that for all $(b_1,b_2)$ there is $(a_1,a_2)$ such that

$b_1=e^{a_1} \cos a_2$   and  $b_2=e^{a_1} \sin a_2$?

How can I show it?

Comment: *Hint* One can eliminate $a_2$ by considering $b_1^2 + b_2^2$.

Comment: Let $f(a,b)=0$, then since $e^a\ne 0$, we have simultaneously $\sin(b)=0 $ and $\cos(b)=0$. It is impossible.

Comment: @Travis So $b_1^2+b_2^2=e^a_1$ which is true for all $a_1$?

Comment: To clarify: are you actually being asked to show $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ (0, 0) \}$ is onto?  That would be the question that would require you to find preimages.  As stated, though, all the question really requires is to show that you can never have $f(x, y) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: @newhere The r.h.s. should be $e^{2 a_1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(b_1,b_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus  (0,0)$.

Take log on $r$ in the [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).

$$r={\sqrt {b_1^{2}+b_2^{2}}}$$
$$a_2 =\operatorname {atan2} (b_2,b_1),$$

where atan2 is a common variation on the arctangent function defined as

$$
\operatorname {atan2} (y,x)={\begin{cases}\arctan({\frac {y}{x}})&{\mbox{if }}x>0\\\arctan({\frac {y}{x}})+\pi &{\mbox{if }}x<0{\mbox{ and }}y\geq 0\\\arctan({\frac {y}{x}})-\pi &{\mbox{if }}x<0{\mbox{ and }}y<0\\{\frac {\pi }{2}}&{\mbox{if }}x=0{\mbox{ and }}y>0\\-{\frac {\pi }{2}}&{\mbox{if }}x=0{\mbox{ and }}y<0\\{\text{undefined}}&{\mbox{if }}x=0{\mbox{ and }}y=0\end{cases}}$$

Then $b_1 = r \cos(a_2)$ and $b_2 = r \sin(a_2)$.  Take $a_1 = \ln r$ so that $b_1 = e^{a_1} \cos(a_2)$ and $b_2 = e^{a_1} \sin(a_2)$.  (Note that $r > 0$ since $(b_1,b_2) \ne (0,0)$)

Comment: Is that notation ${\rm atan}2$ standard? I have never seen it before. Of course, +1

Comment: @IvoTerek I'm not sure whether it's standard, but it's widely used (e.g. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2), [MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html), etc)  You may search `atan2` on Math.SE to see (hundreds of) related questions.

Comment: I'll look it up. Thanks for the references!

Answer (score 2):

You have to show that $\forall (a,b) \ne (0,0)$ we can find $(x,y)$ such that:
$$
a=e^x \cos y \quad \mbox{and} \quad b=e^x\sin y
$$

dividing the two equation we find:
$$ \tan (y)=\frac{b}{a}$$
That gives a value for $y$ for all $a \ne 0$
and squaring and adding the two equation we find:
$$a^2+b^2=e^{2x}$$
that has a solution $x=\frac{1}{2}\ln(a^2+b^2)$ for all $a,b \ne 0$

The case $a=0$ and $b > 0$ gives $ y=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ and $x=\ln b$.

The case $a=0$ and $b < 0$ gives $ y=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ and $x=\ln |b|$.

Comment: why did we get $a^2+b^2=e^2x$ and not  $a^2+b^2=e^x$

Comment: because we square both sides of the  equation, but there was a typo!

Comment: What if $a = 0$ but $b \ne 0$?

Comment: @GNU: I added to my answer. Thank you !